How to handle concurrent purchase attempts for the same number in a raffle system with Next.js, React, and MongoDB?
I am building a website using Next.js, React, and MongoDB Atlas. I want to implement a raffle system where a user can select and purchase a number. Once the payment is completed, the number is assigned to the user. However, I am unsure how to handle the scenario where two users click on the same number at the exact same moment, causing a conflict.
How can I ensure that only one user can purchase a specific number even if multiple users attempt to select it simultaneously? What are the best practices for handling this kind of concurrency issue with MongoDB?

You can simply use an atomic operation. When a purchase is made assign that number to a user if you want to and then make it unavailable.
You can use a schema like this:
{
    "number": 1,
    "isAvailable": true,
    "userId": null
}

Handle the logic where if the same number , which is unavailable now, is requested by another user then you throw a meaningful error.
This way if two users attempt a purchase of the same number then one of them will get a successful purchase and the other will have an error thrown on their end.
Additionally you can explore SWR which can help you in data revalidation on frontend
